# mysql merging two tables if not exist

Tags: mysql

I want to merge two tables, but not the duplicate entries with similar id field.

But I get error after:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, name) 
      SELECT id, name FROM table2 WHERE table2.id NOT_IN (SELECT id FROM table1);
```

Comment: what error you receive back?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT_IN(SELECT id FROM table1)' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `NOT_IN` in `NOT IN`, as this is the correct synthax

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, name) 
SELECT id, name FROM table2 WHERE table2.id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM table1);
```